# how does html5test.com work,the code analysis?

Tags: analysis, html5test

My teacher wants to me give a speech about html5test.com. I know it's a test about how your browser supports html5. I got the source code on github, but I just can't understand it. How can I use html5test in my own code programming?

Answer (score 0):

Well, they test for support of the HTML features (or APIs) in your browser, and scores your browser according to that.

To use something like that in your own project, you can check out Modernizr. It's much more simpler, and has more features.

[Modernizr - the feature detection library](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: you mean I can't use html5test in my own project? but my teacher wants me to do that